# Passing parameters to VFP 9 form

Tags: forms, visual-foxpro

I have a form in VFP 9 that is usually called from another form with 2 parameters.
I've got a strange thing happening: when I execute `DO FORM jobless_add` in command window, the first parameter is always set to "2", while no parameters were added.

As a result, I have `EMPTY(par1) == false` and `EMPTY(par2) == true`. After that I've tried to open the form in the normal way (from the other form's button click with 2 parameters) and I've gotten this result in `debugger`

This is my first visit, so I cant insert images. Link: [image](http://img29.imageshack.us/img29/8378/22323i.png)
*(hint: Locals: all ok, Watches: "2" again)*

NOTE: I have no global variables yet.

Comment: try to use code tags. It makes questions easier to read. Welcome and good luck!

Comment: Is there any chance that the currently selected table has a field called 'jobless_id'?

Comment: To clarify further, a table's field takes precedence over a memory variable if you reference just the unqualified field name.  Try "m.jobless_id" to explicitly reference the variable (i.e., the parameter).

Comment: thank you, absolutely right :) It is so simple, but not so obvious for newbie)

Comment: hm, how can I close question an mark it as "solved"?

Comment: Great, glad it helped!  I've reposted my response as an actual answer rather than a comment.  You should select it as 'the' answer now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You most likely have a table with a field/column called 'jobless_id'.

To clarify further, a table's field takes precedence over a memory variable if you reference just the unqualified field name. Try "m.jobless_id" to explicitly reference the variable (i.e., the parameter).